# As a (micro) behavioral economist looking for a faculty job, how should I present my research approach/skill set?

Tags: behavioral-economics, experimental-economics

I am asking as someone who has applied behavioral econ theory to design lab experiments and a couple field experiments. I notice that there is a bias against experiment-based research on the market.

... What can I write to demonstrate the value addition of my skills, besides my knowledge of behavioral econ theory. Or what are some impactful ways you have seen others present their skills as behavioral economists? Or how do you value the skills a behavioral economist brings to your research team?

I am applying for positions that get applications from people with labor, environment, and development econ backgrounds,  and I'd like some advice on how best to market a behavioral econ background.

I realize it's hard to give advice without knowing the kind of research projects I've worked on, but I'll appreciate even general, high-level advice.

Comment: Questions on workings of academia belong to the academia.se so it is being migrated there.